# Problem with application with struts2 lib

Tags: struts2, pom.xml

This is my pom.xml dependencies. I'm trying to build and deploy an application on a Wildfly server. I'm moving an old program to the maven structure, so I'm deleting old .jars from lib folder and adding dependencies in pom.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ar.com.fdvs/DynamicJasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dans</groupId>
            <artifactId>dans-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.30</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

When my app is deployed and I try to see the welcome page I got following error in logs of a server (I'm using wildfly, maybe it's important to say). I have dependency to commons-io so the File should be good

```
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.io.File
File: File.java
Method: <init>
Line: 423 - java/io/File.java:423:-1
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - Class: java.io.File
File: File.java
Method: <init>
Line: 423 - java/io/File.java:423:-1
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:950)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:155)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:122)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:205)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$JBossFileRevision.build(FileManager.java:240)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:143)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:105)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:935)
        ... 53 more
```

I'm not sure what can be the problem, I think that I have all dependencies needed for struts2 already in my pom.

Comment: How are you packaging your app? What does your app structure and config look like?

Comment: The solution to my problem was to use lower version of struts library. I'm packaging in a .war

Comment: Just keep in mind that 2.3 was EOLed a couple of years ago.